# Keycloak: Null Pointer Exception

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-gatekeeper

I have upgraded the keycloak version from 16.1.1 to 17.0.0. On login page, I started getting following exception.

```
ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (executor-thread-0) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.keycloak.protocol.AuthorizationEndpointBase.handleBrowserAuthenticationRequest(AuthorizationEndpointBase.java:107)
at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.buildAuthorizationCodeAuthorizationResponse(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:326)
at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.process(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:189)
at org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.buildGet(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:112)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

What should I do to solve this issue?